# How can I use an existing Directive within a custom python-sphinx Directive/extension?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I'd like to create a custom `Directive` that uses the an existing Directive (`code-block` in this example) in it's implementation.

The manual equivalent of this in reStructuredText would be:

```
.. mydirective:: py

   .. code-block: py
        
      print("Hello world")
```

However, I would like the `code-block` to be created within `my-directive`'s definition. I found an example that hard-codes the appropriate `reStructuredText` for the existing Directive (below), but this depends on the parser using `rST`.

```py
class MyDirective(Directive):
    has_content = True

    def run(self):
        # Do custom stuff...

        # Use code-block Directive
        new_content = [
            '.. tab:: {}'.format(json.dumps(tab_args)),
            '   {}'.format(tab_name),
            '',
            '   .. code-block:: {}'.format(lang),
        ]

        if 'linenos' in self.options:
            new_content.append('      :linenos:')

        new_content.append('')

        for idx, line in enumerate(new_content):
            self.content.data.insert(idx, line)
            self.content.items.insert(idx, (None, idx))

        node = nodes.container()
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, node)
        return node.children
```

How could I implement this in a parser-independent fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, my solution was:

```
from sphinx.directives.code import CodeBlock


class CodeTabDirective(CodeBlock):
    """ Tab directive with a codeblock as its content"""

    def run(self):
        self.assert_has_content()
        
        code_block = super().run()[0]

        # Set anything required by OtherDirective

        node = OtherDirective.run(self)[0]  # Generates container
        node.append(code_block)  # Put code block inside container

        return [node]
```

Where `OtherDirective` was another existing directive.

I wasn't able to subclass both directives and use their functionality via `super`, as I needed to call a method named `run` from both.

### Update

You can see the final solution in place in the [CodeTabDirective](https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-tabs/blob/de7e7126198aac5e9598e099f9a2f4cd8e089e55/sphinx_tabs/tabs.py#L181) of `sphinx-tabs`.